# Discount not applied on Event registration

Tags: cividiscount

Discounts stopped working on our website, is anyone having same issue recently?

We tried deleting all the codes and created new one with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount/-/issues/308) on recent version of CiviCRM

Submitted PR at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29829

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, So reverting the cividiscount extension should fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I meant CiviCRM version 5.71 has a regression, i have submitted a PR, added the PR link in the comment

Comment: That fixed the problem

Comment: Fixed it for me as well.